# MS SQL Выбрать значения из диапазона

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
Справочник сотрудников
CREATE TABLE Employee (
  ID INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
  Code VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL UNIQUE,
  Name VARCHAR(255)
)
 
INSERT INTO Employee (ID, Code, Name)
VALUES (1, 'E01', 'Ivanov Ivan Ivanovich'),
  (2, 'E02', 'Petrov Petr Petrovich'),
  (3, 'E03', 'Sidorov Sidr Sidorovich')
 
 
-- Отпуска сотрудников
CREATE TABLE Vacation (
  ID INT NOT NULL IDENTITY(1, 1) PRIMARY KEY,
  ID_Employee INT NOT NULL REFERENCES Employee(ID),
  DateBegin DATE NOT NULL,
  DateEnd DATE NOT NULL
)
 
INSERT INTO Vacation (ID_Employee, DateBegin, DateEnd)
VALUES (1, '2019-08-10', '2019-09-01')
  ,(1, '2019-12-29', '2020-01-14')
  ,(2, '2019-05-01', '2019-05-15')
```

Есть такой код, необходимо выбрать сотрудников которые были в отпуске ОДНОВРЕМЕННО.
Вот код

```
SELECT DISTINCT e1.Name Name1, e2.Name Name2
FROM Vacation v1
JOIN Vacation v2 ON v1.DateBegin < v2.DateBegin AND v2.DateBegin < v1.DateEnd
JOIN Employee e1 ON e1.ID = v1.ID_Employee
JOIN Employee e2 ON e2.ID = v2.ID_Employee
```

Необходимо сделать запрос без distinct.
Еще один момент. Как появляются 2 таблицы e1 e2  У меня же одна таблица, как  сравниваются 2 таблицы?

Comment: Как алиазы могут клонировать таблицу?

Comment: Каждый join - это дополнительный вложеный цикл по таблице. Если вы в таблицу где 4 строки несвязано добавите такую же саму таблицу - вы получите 16 строк, где каждая строка с первой таблицей будет сопоставлена с каждой строкой из второй таблицы. Условие при on позваляет сократить к-во комбинаций.

Answer (score 0):

```
-- Common Table Expression (CTE) - join сотрудников с отпусками.
with employee_vacations as (
    select *
    from employee e
    join vacation v on e.id = v.id_employee
)
select
    employee_list
from (
    -- Группируем по уникальной комбинации даты начала и даты конца отпуска,
    -- считаем count - сколько сотрудников с такой датой начала и конца отпуска
    -- (в этом подзапросе в итоговую выборку попадут сотрудники с уникальными промежутками отпуска - могут быть записи-агрегаты с count() = 1),
    -- и объединяем в строку через запятую сотрудников из каждой записи с одинаковой датой начала и датой конца отпуска.
    -- distinct - перестраховка на случай дублей в исходных записях.
    select
        count(1) as unique_employees_count,
        string_agg(distinct(ev.name), ',') as employee_list
    from employee_vacations ev
    group by datebegin, dateend
) employees_by_vacation_period ebvp
-- Осталось только отфильтровать уникальные комбинации даты начала и даты конца отпуска, у которых больше одного сотрудника.
where unique_employees_count > 1;
```

Протестировал на PostgreSQL, но используются только конструкции из generic SQL.
В PostgreSQL есть тип данных array: вместо `string_agg` можно использовать `array_agg`. Возможно, в Microsoft SQL Server тоже можно сгруппировать сотрудников как-нибудь покрасивее.

Также, аккуратно с code style: у вас у части колонок snake_case, у части - CamelCase. Рекомендую везде использовать snake_case и маленькие буквы, т.к.полагаться на разделение на большие и маленькие буквы ненадёжно - некоторые SQL СУБД case insensitive.

По поводу того, что у меня ключевые слова не заглавными буквами - написание ключевых слов заглавными буквами было актуально, когда редакторы не умели подсвечивать синтаксис. Сейчас в SQL можно всё печатать маленькими буквами.